# call the same python script with varying arguments and parse the argments

Tags: python, parsing, arguments

I need to call different python scipts from another script depending on the parameters.

The main scipt is invoked from another script by pasiing parameters

EX:

```
----runner.py invokes----

python testfolder/subrun.py -s script1 -d xyz  -l abc -a test1

python testfolder/subrun.py -s script2 -d xyz  -l abc -a test2 -e test@test.com -u myid
```

depending on the parameter s i have to invoke `script1.py` or `script2.py`

How can I parse other arguments in `subrun.py` depending on the parameter `-s`. The number of parameters vary depending on script1 or script2

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script parser')
parser.add_argument('-s', "--script_name", help='specify script')

args = parser.parse_args()

if(args.script_name == "script1"):
    #load script 1
else
    #load script 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon James' code which is actually missing one part namely the rest of the arguments. I think without this it will most likely fail due to unknown arguments.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script parser')
parser.add_argument('-s', "--script_name", help='specify script')
parser.add_argument('script_args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
# parsed_args.script_args now contains a list of the rest of the args
# that you can pass on to whatever script that was chosen.

if(parsed_args.script_name == "script1"):
    #load script 1
else
    #load script 2
```

Comment: I get an error : unrecognized arguments: -d. If i add another parameter "-d" other than -s   @Jahaja

Answer (score 0):

I like functional style for argument parsing. Create a main method that takes argv as argument and recursively parses arguments.

```
import sys
if __name__=="__main__":
     main(sys.argv)

def main(argv):
   if len(argv)==0:
       start program
   elif argv[0]=="-s":
       handle script name from argv[1]
       main(argv[2:])
   elif argv[0]=="-d":
       handle d arg from argv[1]
       main(argv[2:])
   else:
       sys.stderr.write("unrecognized command line option: " + argv[0] + "\n")
       exit(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

I just use sys.argv, here is an example:

```
import sys

for argument in sys.argv:
    if argument == "--debug" or argument == "-d":
        #do debug stuff
    elif argument == "--help" or argument == "-h":
        #do help stuff
    elif argument == "--log" or argument == "-l":
        #do log stuff
```

so if you run this as "test.py -d -h" it launches and runs doing both the debug and the help stuff but ignoring the log stuff. From this you can easily expand and modify things as you need. Here is a larger snippet that I frequently use at the start of large programs.

```
import sys

for argument in sys.argv:
    if argument == "--debug" or argument == "-d":
        debug = True
    elif argument == "--help" or argument == "-h":
        display_help()
    elif argument == "--log" or argument == "-l":
        logready = True
    elif argument == "1":
        if logready == True: 
            logready = False
            loglevel = 1
        else:
            print("Unknown argument: %s" % argument)
            usage()
    elif argument == "2":
        if logready == True:  
            logready = False
            loglevel = 2
        else:
            print("Unknown argument: %s" % argument)
            usage()
    elif argument == "3":
        if logready == True:  
            logready = False
            loglevel = 3
        else:
            print("Unknown argument: %s" % argument)
            usage()
    elif argument == "4":
        if logready == True:  
            logready = False
            loglevel = 4
    else:
        print("Unknown argument: %s" % argument)
        display_help()
```

as you can see it allows people to specify at launch whether they want debug mode, the level of logging to use, or to display the help. If someone enters an unrecongized argument then it defaults to displaying the help.